# How to delete DNS records via ARM template for Azure DNS zone

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-dns

I have an ARM template for an Azure DNS zone that has many `Microsoft.Network/dnszones/*` resources for `A`, `CNAME`, `TXT` records, etc. I've been able to deploy new records and change records successfully through deployments.

I just noticed however that when I deleted resources corresponding to some DNS records in the ARM template, a deployment of that template didn't actually delete the records in the Azure DNS zone, although the deployment succeeded.

This seems like it breaks the declarative nature of ARM templates if I deleted a resource in the template and it still exists after deployment without errors.

Or am I misunderstanding something about the way the resource provider works?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Comment: thanks @BhargaviAnnadevara that answers it!

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara are you sure that it works at all? My experience says its not. It wiped all other resources from the resource group itself, but not a dns records inside dns zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modes in which ARM templates can be deployed:

- **Incremental:** In incremental mode, Resource Manager leaves unchanged resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template. Resources in the template are added to the resource group.
- **Complete:** In complete mode, Resource Manager deletes resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template.

The default mode is **incremental**, which is why you're not seeing the deleted resources being removed.

To set the [deployment mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes) to `Complete` explicitly when deploying with PowerShell, use the `Mode` parameter as:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -Mode Complete `
  -Name ExampleDeployment `
  -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup `
  -TemplateFile c:\MyTemplates\storage.json
```

> **Tip:** Always use the [what-if operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell) before deploying a template
> in complete mode. What-if shows you which resources will be created,
> deleted, or modified. Use what-if to avoid unintentionally deleting
> resources.